# Getting internal server error code 500 when trying to call one jsp page from another

Tags: jsp

I've added one new method "encrypt" inside a jsp page. After adding this method there is an error with status code 500 occurring, but before adding this method there was no error. The following is the jsp page where there is an error occurring. Can anyone help me to find out where the error is?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*,java.util.*" %>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.IOException"%>
<%@page import="java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException"%>
<%@page import="java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException"%>
<%@page import="java.security.InvalidKeyException"%>
<%@page import="java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException"%>
<%@page import="java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec"%>
<%@page import="java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException"%>
<%@page import="java.security.spec.KeySpec"%>
<%@page import="java.security.spec.KeySpec"%>
<%@page import="java.security.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec"%>
<%@page import="javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec"%> 
<%@page import="java.util.Base64"%>
 <%
    String op = request.getParameter("op");
    String saltID = (String)request.getAttribute("csrfPreventionSalt");
    String key = "ezeon8547";
    String enc = encrypt(key, saltID);
    System.out.println("Encrypted text: "+enc);
    if(saltID != null)
    {
        session.setAttribute("crsf", saltID);
    }       
    if(op==null) {  //out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>"+session.getAttribute("REGISTRATION_ERROR"));
        session.removeAttribute("registerBean");
        session.removeAttribute("REGISTRATION_ERROR");
        //session.invalidate();
    }
%>
<%
    if(session.getAttribute("REGISTRATION_ERROR")!=null) {

    }
    try {
        if(true) {
   String address = "my address"
   String state = "my state";
   String city = "my city";
   String pincode = "500100";   
%>
<table align="left" border="0" width="80%">
<tr>
    <td></td> <!-- For right space -->
    <!-- Data Table STart Below -->
    <td>
    <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr><td width="100%">
        <div class="frmtbldata">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="1" style="font-size: 1.1em">
            <tr>
                <th height="20"  class="centr" colspan="2" valign="top">Edit Address
             </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="40%" >Enter your existing address</th>
                <td ><input type="text"  name="addressOld" id="addressOld" value="<%=address%>" readonly class="reporttitle1"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="40%" > <font class="contenttext">Enter your existing city</td>
                <td class="t0"><input type="text"  name="cityOld" id="cityOld" value="<%=city%>" readonly class="reporttitle1"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="40%" >Enter your existing state</th>
                <td ><input type="text"  name="stateOld" id="stateOld" value="<%=state%>" readonly class="reporttitle1"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="40%" >Enter your existing pincode</th>
                <td ><input type="text"  name="pincodeOld" id="pincodeOld" value="<%=pincode%>" readonly class="reporttitle1"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="40%">Enter your new address</th>
                <td ><input type="text"  name="addressNew" id="addressNew" value="" class="reporttitle1"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="40%">Enter your new city</th>
                <td><input type="text"  name="cityNew" id="cityNew" value="" class="reporttitle1"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="40%" >Enter your new state</font></th>
                <td class="t0"><input type="text"  name="stateNew" id="stateNew" value="" class="reporttitle1"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th width="40%">Enter your new pincode</td>
                <td ><input type="text"  name="pincodeNew" id="pincodeNew" value="<%= saltID %>"  maxlength="6" class="reporttitle1"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
                <td ><input type="text" name="saltToken" id="saltToken" value="<%= saltID %>"></input>
                </td>
                <!--<td ><input type="hidden" name="crsf" id="crsf" value="<%= saltID %>"></input> -->
                </td>
            <th height="30" class="centr" colspan="2">
                <input type="button" value="Submit" id="Submit" onClick="validateAddress('/registration/tv/trades/newStructure/editModule/editAddressConfirm.jsp?module=A&Token=<%= saltID %>')">
                <img src="/images/trans.gif" width="80" height="1">
                <!--<input type="reset" name ="reset" value="Clear" > -->
            </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
    </td>
    <!-- Data Table end -->
    <td></td><!-- For left space -->
</tr>
</table>
<%}else{
System.out.println("Invalid user in edit address >>>>>>>>>>>>");
}
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println("Invalid user in edit address >>>>>>>>>>>>.Please try later");
}
%>
<%!
    public String encrypt(String secretKey, String plainText) 
            throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, 
            InvalidKeySpecException, 
            NoSuchPaddingException, 
            InvalidKeyException,
            InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, 
            UnsupportedEncodingException, 
            IllegalBlockSizeException, 
            BadPaddingException,
            Exception
            {
                Cipher ecipher;
                // 8-byte Salt
                byte[] salt = {(byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0x9B, (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0x32, (byte) 0x56, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x03};
                // Iteration count
                int iterationCount = 19;
                //Key generation for enc and desc
                KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(secretKey.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
                SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);    
                 // Prepare the parameter to the ciphers
                AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

                //Enc process
                ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
                ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
                String charSet="UTF-8";
                byte[] inP = plainText.getBytes(charSet);
                byte[] outP = ecipher.doFinal(inP);
                String encStr = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(outP);
                return encStr;
            }
%>
```

I know it is not good practice to write the java code inside jsp page.

Comment: Where is the stacktrace? Add it to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your time  @JozefChocholacek . I have removed the java code from jsp and it is working now. Actually there was not stackstrace, this jsp page was getting called from another jsp page and browser returned the 500 response code.